# Realloc causing program to crash

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Currently trying to write menu based program that asks user for student records, after initial records are entered I want user to have option to add more record slots but when I try to realloc my 2d pointer array my program crashes, specifically after the 2nd function is called.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 21
void printRecords(int* size, char **fistName, char **lastName, float *grade);
void addRecord(int* size, char** firstName, char** lastName, float *grade);

int  main(void) { /* Minimum measure check */
    int size = 0, *check = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *check = 1;
    while (check) {
        printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min 5): ");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        if (size < 5)
            printf("Size entered was below the minimum.\n");
        else
            check = 0; }
    free(check);

                                        /* Dynamic Memory Allocation */
    char **firstName = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*)), **lastName = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*)); 
    float *grade = (float*)malloc(size * sizeof(float));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        firstName[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH *  sizeof(char));
        lastName[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char)); }

    printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record),\nwith following format first name last name score:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; (i)++)
        scanf("%s %s %f", &firstName[i][0], &lastName[i][0], &grade[i]);

    int option = 1;
    while (option != 0) { /* Option Menu */
        printf("Print records (press 1)\nAdd new record(press 2)\nDelete record(s)(press 3)\nSeach by last name(press 4)\nSort by score(press 5)\nSort by last name(press 6)\nFind the median score(press 7)\nExit the program(press 0)\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            printRecords(&size, firstName, lastName, grade);
            break;
        case 2:
            addRecord(&size, firstName, lastName, grade);
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printRecords(int* size, char **firstName, char **lastName, float grade[]) { /* Option 1 */
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < *size; i++)
                printf("First Name : %s, Last Name : %s, Score : %.2f\n", firstName[i], lastName[i], grade[i]); 
    }

void addRecord(int* size, char** firstName, char** lastName, float* grade) { /* Option 2 */
    char **a;
    float *c;
    (*size) += 1;

    a = (char **)realloc(firstName, *size * sizeof(char*)); /* Error */
    if (a != NULL) //realloc was successful
        firstName = a;
    else //there was an error

    a = (char **)realloc(lastName, *size * sizeof(char*));
    if (a != NULL) //realloc was successful
        lastName = a;
    else; //there was an error 

    c = (float *)realloc(grade, *size * sizeof(float*));
    grade = c;
    firstName[*size - 1] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    lastName[*size - 1] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s %s %f", &firstName[*size][0], &lastName[*size][0], &grade[*size]);
    }
```

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc()` in c `void *` is converted to any pointer type automatically, and please format your code in a readable style.

Comment: `firstName = a;` not assign original(firstName not change in main).

Comment: `else //there was an error` needs Sentence.

Comment: `scanf("%20s %20s %f", firstName[*size - 1], lastName[*size - 1], &grade[*size - 1]);`

Comment: firstName = a; not assign original(firstName not change in main) , may you please explain why this is not happening I thought this is how pass by reference worked.

Comment: @0123 Yes, it is. But C doesn't have pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** there is an error in a missing `;` resulting in `lastName` not being reallocated

```
if (a != NULL) //realloc was successful
    firstName = a;
else //there was an error                                  <<-- missing ;

a = (char **)realloc(lastName, *size * sizeof(char*));  // <<-- executed under "else"
```

In fact, `lastName` is assigned the same value as `firstName` with the following

```
if (a != NULL) //realloc was successful
    lastName = a;
```

Also, a comment about about your use of `check`. There are some things wrong with your input loop. It's quite unnecessary to allocate memory for a simple `int`. You aren't even using `check` as a pointer (`check = 0;` will cause `free()` to fail, and a memory leak).

```
int size = 0, *check = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*check = 1;
while (check) {         // <==== error should be *check
    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    if (size < 5)
        printf("Size entered was below the minimum.\n");
    else
        check = 0;      // <==== error should be *check
    }
free(check);
```

This would be much easier, and you don't even need `check`.

```
int size;
do {
    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    if (size < 5)
        printf("Size entered was below the minimum.\n");
    }
while (size < 5);
```

Comment: You miss to address the fact that the address returned by those two calls to `realloc()` is never passed outside of `addRecord()` but is lost on leaving the function.

Answer (score 1):

C is pass by value.

The changes applied to `firstName` and `lastName` in `addREcord()` are lost after the function returned, as those two vairbales carry copeis of the variables passed as argument to the call of `addRecord()`.

Change the definition of `addRecord()` from

```
void addRecord(int* size, char** firstName, char** lastName, float* grade);
```

to be

```
void addRecord(int* size, char*** pfirstName, char*** plastName, float* grade);
```

and inside `addRecord()` replace all `firstName` with `(*pfirstName)` and all `lastName` with `(*plastName)`

(Interessting enough you did the correctly for `size`.)

Call  `addRecord()` like this:

```
addRecord(&size, &firstName, &lastName, grade);
```