# reallocation of 2d arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, allocation

I want to reallocate a 2d array, so that the arrays in the second array become bigger, so the things I want to store are bigger than the arrays I want to store them in and I want to make the arrays bigger. The problem is that I do not really know how to do this. I got it to compile without errors, but in Valgrind I saw a lot of memory errors, so I do something wrong. I saw [a previous question about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007171/using-alloc-on-a-2d-array-c) but I do not really understand it, so any help and explanation on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I have this so far.

```
int **create2darray(int a, int b) {
  int i;
  int **array;

  array = malloc(a * sizeof(int *));
  assert(array != NULL);
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    array[i] = calloc(b, sizeof(int));
    assert(array[i] != NULL);
  }
  return array;
}

int **reallocArray(int **array, int size, int i) {
  int i;
  int **safe_array;
  safe_array = realloc(*array ,2 * size);
  assert(safe_array != NULL);
  array = safe_array;
  return array;
}

void free2DArray(int **array, int m) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    free(array[i]);
  }
}


int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {
  int i;
  int size;
  int **testArray = create2darray(1, 10);
  size = 10;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    testArray[0][i] = 2;
  }
  testArray[0] = reallocArray(testArray, size, 0);
  size = 2 * size;
  for(i = 9; i < size; i++) {
    testArray[0][i] = 3;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d", testArray[0][i]);
    free2DArray(testArray, size);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to re-allocate or what the last parameter to `reallocArray` is. At present, you only re-allocate the first row. When you want your whole array to grow, you must do a two-level re-allocation just as in `createArray`.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to increase the number of columns in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function `reallocArray` which realaoctes the outer array and all the inner arrays too.
Adapt youre code like this:

```
#include <malloc.h> 

int **reallocArray( int **array, int oldSizeA, int newSizeA, int newSizeB )
{
    // realloc the array of pointers ( allocates new memory if array == NULL )
    int **safe_array = realloc( array, newSizeA * sizeof( int* ) );
    assert(safe_array != NULL);
    if ( safe_array == NULL )
        return array;
    array = safe_array;

    // realloc the inner arrays of int ( allocates new memory if i >= oldSizeA )
    for ( int i = 0; i < newSizeA; i ++ )
    {
        int *temp = NULL;    // allocate new memory if i >= oldSizeA
        if ( i < oldSizeA )  
            temp = array[i]; // reallocate array[i] if i < oldSizeA

        temp = realloc( temp, newSizeB * sizeof( int ) );
        assert( temp != NULL );
        if ( temp == NULL )
            return array;
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Use function `reallocArray` in your function `create2darray` to create your array. If the input paramter of `ralloc` is `NULL`, then new dynamic memory is allocated.

```
int **create2darray( int sizeA, int sizeB )
{
    return reallocArray( NULL, 0, sizeA, sizeB );
}
```

First you have to `free` the inner arrays of int in a loop, then you have to `free` the array of pointers:

```
void free2DArray( int **array, int sizeA )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i ++)
       free( array[i] );
    free( array );
}


int main( int argv, char *argc[] ){

    int sizeA = 1;
    int sizeB = 10;
    int **testArray = create2darray( sizeA, sizeB );
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeB; i++ ) {
        testArray[0][i] = 2; 
    }

    int oldSizeA = sizeA;
    int oldSizeB = sizeB;
    sizeB = 2*sizeB;
    testArray = reallocArray( testArray, oldSizeA, sizeA, sizeB );
    for( int i = oldSizeB; i < sizeB; i++ ) {
        testArray[0][i] = 3;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeB; i++ ) {
        printf("%d", testArray[0][i]);
    }

    free2DArray(testArray, sizeA );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot the second free. I fixed that now, but I do not understand the last if-statement. The if-statement never works right?. if temp is idd NULL then the assert will interupt, but the code itself is really nice. I did not know that the pointers had to be safe temporary, so thanks :D
          `(temp = realloc( temp, newSizeB * sizeof( int ) );

          assert( temp != NULL );

          if ( temp == NULL )

             return array;

            array[i] = temp;

            }

            return array;

        }`

Answer (score 0):

In `Free2DArray()`, you `free()` the individual arrays of integers, but not the "outer" dimension of the array which holds the integer pointers.
You could add another call to `free()` after the loop to take care of that.

In `main()`:

```
for(i = 0; i <size; i++) {
    printf("%d", testArray[0][i]);
    free2DArray(testArray, size);
}
```

you will end up `free()`-ing the (inner) integer arrays multiple times.
The call to `free2DArray()` should be outside the loop.